# ModuleNotFoundError when running Optimization examples from floris v1.1.4 develop branch

Tags: floris

I have downloaded a local editable installation of floris version 1.1.4 develop branch and am trying to run the Optimization examples:

- example_layout_optimization.py
- example_power_density_optimization.py
- example_yaw_optimization.py
- example_yaw_optimization_no_class.py
- example_yaw_optimization_wind_rose_no_class.py

in the following manner

`floris\examples\optimization>python example_layout_optimization.py`

However, for each I get the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "example_power_density_optimization.py", line 36, in <module>
    tmp = opt.optimization.Optimization(model=model, solver='SLSQP')
  File "c:\users\nilsg\floris\floris\tools\optimization\optimization.py", line 41, in __init__
    self.reinitialize(solver=solver)
  File "c:\users\nilsg\floris\floris\tools\optimization\optimization.py", line 78, in reinitialize
    self._reinitialize(solver=solver)
  File "c:\users\nilsg\floris\floris\tools\optimization\optimization.py", line 46, in _reinitialize
    import pyoptsparse
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyoptsparse'
```

Any help much appreciate, and, as this is my first post I expect to have to rephrase the question because I am unlikely to have done so well.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the error, the python installation cannot find the module `pyoptsparse`. This can occur if the module is not installed or is not on the python path. Currently, [pyoptsparse](https://github.com/mdolab/pyoptsparse) is not installed automatically with [FLORIS](https://github.com/NREL/floris), but requires the user to install it manually, so this is most likely the case. Automatic installation with FLORIS will hopefully be implemented in the near future.

In order to install pyoptsparse, I would refer you to their [installation documentation](http://mdolab.engin.umich.edu/docs/packages/pyoptsparse/doc/install.html). There you will find the dependencies that pyoptsparse requires (which you may already have), and the commands to install the package. I would recommend for ease, after verifying/installing the required dependencies, to use the

```
>>> python setup.py install --user
```

which will install the package to the `~./local` directory which is usually on the python path.

Comment: Thank you @bayc. Unfortunately, I am now having trouble installing the PyOptSparse package, I've posted another Stack Overflow question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60323156/fortran-compiler-problem-installing-pyoptsparse)

Comment: @insatiableturtle Were you able to get the optimization examples to run?

Comment: I couldn't install PyOptSparse but I did manage to get the SciPy optimisation examples to run yes.