# Fortran compiler error installing PyOptSparse

Tags: python, installation, gfortran

I am trying to install the PyOptSparse package via the Anaconda Prompt using

```
(FYP_py37_32bit) C:\Users\nilsg\pyoptsparse>python setup.py install --user
```

but keep getting the following error

```
compiling Fortran sources
Fortran f77 compiler: C:\Users\nilsg\Miniconda3\envs\FYP_py37_32bit\Library\mingw-w64\bin\gfortran.exe -Wall -g -ffixed-form -fno-second-underscore -O3 -funroll-loops
Fortran f90 compiler: C:\Users\nilsg\Miniconda3\envs\FYP_py37_32bit\Library\mingw-w64\bin\gfortran.exe -Wall -g -fno-second-underscore -O3 -funroll-loops
Fortran fix compiler: C:\Users\nilsg\Miniconda3\envs\FYP_py37_32bit\Library\mingw-w64\bin\gfortran.exe -Wall -g -ffixed-form -fno-second-underscore -Wall -g -fno-second-underscore -O3 -funroll-loops
compile options: '-Ibuild\src.win32-3.7\build\src.win32-3.7\pyoptsparse\pyFSQP\source\f2py -IC:\Users\nilsg\Miniconda3\envs\FYP_py37_32bit\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\nilsg\Miniconda3\envs\FYP_py37_32bit\include -IC:\Users\nilsg\Miniconda3\envs\FYP_py37_32bit\include -c'
gfortran.exe:f77: build\src.win32-3.7\pyoptsparse\pyFSQP\source\f2py\ffsqp-f2pywrappers.f
C:\Users\nilsg\Miniconda3\envs\FYP_py37_32bit\Library\mingw-w64\bin\gfortran.exe -Wall -g -Wall -g -shared build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\build\src.win32-3.7\pyoptsparse\pyfsqp\source\f2py\ffsqpmodule.o build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\build\src.win32-3.7\build\src.win32-3.7\pyoptsparse\pyfsqp\source\f2py\fortranobject.o build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\build\src.win32-3.7\pyoptsparse\pyFSQP\source\f2py\ffsqp-f2pywrappers.o -LC:\Users\nilsg\Miniconda3\envs\FYP_py37_32bit\Library\mingw-w64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\5.3.0 -LC:\Users\nilsg\Miniconda3\envs\FYP_py37_32bit\libs -LC:\Users\nilsg\Miniconda3\envs\FYP_py37_32bit\PCbuild\win32 -Lbuild\temp.win32-3.7 -lffsqp -lpython37 -lgfortran -o build\lib.win32-3.7\pyoptsparse\pyFSQP\ffsqp.cp37-win32.pyd
build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\build\src.win32-3.7\pyoptsparse\pyfsqp\source\f2py\ffsqpmodule.o:ffsqpmodule.c:(.data+0x358): undefined reference to `ffsqp_'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: Command "C:\Users\nilsg\Miniconda3\envs\FYP_py37_32bit\Library\mingw-w64\bin\gfortran.exe -Wall -g -Wall -g -shared build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\build\src.win32-3.7\pyoptsparse\pyfsqp\source\f2py\ffsqpmodule.o build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\build\src.win32-3.7\build\src.win32-3.7\pyoptsparse\pyfsqp\source\f2py\fortranobject.o build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\build\src.win32-3.7\pyoptsparse\pyFSQP\source\f2py\ffsqp-f2pywrappers.o -LC:\Users\nilsg\Miniconda3\envs\FYP_py37_32bit\Library\mingw-w64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\5.3.0 -LC:\Users\nilsg\Miniconda3\envs\FYP_py37_32bit\libs -LC:\Users\nilsg\Miniconda3\envs\FYP_py37_32bit\PCbuild\win32 -Lbuild\temp.win32-3.7 -lffsqp -lpython37 -lgfortran -o build\lib.win32-3.7\pyoptsparse\pyFSQP\ffsqp.cp37-win32.pyd" failed with exit status 1
```

My conda environment includes the following packages

```
# packages in environment at C:\Users\nilsg\Miniconda3\envs\FYP_py37_32bit:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
astroid                   2.3.3                    pypi_0    pypi
atomicwrites              1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
attrs                     19.3.0                   pypi_0    pypi
ca-certificates           2020.1.1                      0
certifi                   2019.11.28               py37_0
chardet                   3.0.4                    pypi_0    pypi
colorama                  0.4.3                    pypi_0    pypi
cycler                    0.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
floris                    1.1.4                     dev_0    <develop>
h5pyd                     0.3.3                    pypi_0    pypi
idna                      2.9                      pypi_0    pypi
importlib-metadata        1.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
isort                     4.3.21                   pypi_0    pypi
kiwisolver                1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
lazy-object-proxy         1.4.3                    pypi_0    pypi
libpython                 2.1                      py37_0
m2w64-binutils            2.25.1                        5    msys2
m2w64-bzip2               1.0.6                         6    msys2
m2w64-crt-git             5.0.0.4636.2595836               2    msys2
m2w64-gcc                 5.3.0                         6    msys2
m2w64-gcc-ada             5.3.0                         6    msys2
m2w64-gcc-fortran         5.3.0                         6    msys2
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6    msys2
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7    msys2
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7    msys2
m2w64-gcc-objc            5.3.0                         6    msys2
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2    msys2
m2w64-headers-git         5.0.0.4636.c0ad18a               2    msys2
m2w64-isl                 0.16.1                        2    msys2
m2w64-libiconv            1.14                          6    msys2
m2w64-libmangle-git       5.0.0.4509.2e5a9a2               2    msys2
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2    msys2
m2w64-make                4.1.2351.a80a8b8               2    msys2
m2w64-mpc                 1.0.3                         3    msys2
m2w64-mpfr                3.1.4                         4    msys2
m2w64-pkg-config          0.29.1                        2    msys2
m2w64-toolchain           5.3.0                         7    msys2
m2w64-tools-git           5.0.0.4592.90b8472               2    msys2
m2w64-windows-default-manifest 6.4                           3    msys2
m2w64-winpthreads-git     5.0.0.4634.697f757               2    msys2
m2w64-zlib                1.2.8                        10    msys2
matplotlib                3.1.3                    pypi_0    pypi
mccabe                    0.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
more-itertools            8.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1    msys2
numpy                     1.16.3                   pypi_0    pypi
openssl                   1.1.1d               he774522_4
packaging                 20.1                     pypi_0    pypi
pandas                    0.24.2                   pypi_0    pypi
pip                       20.0.2                   py37_1
pluggy                    0.13.1                   pypi_0    pypi
py                        1.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pylint                    2.4.4                    pypi_0    pypi
pyparsing                 2.4.6                    pypi_0    pypi
pyproj                    2.1.3                    pypi_0    pypi
pytest                    5.3.5                    pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.7.6                h60c2a47_2
python-dateutil           2.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pytz                      2019.3                   pypi_0    pypi
requests                  2.23.0                   pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
seaborn                   0.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                45.2.0                   py37_0
six                       1.14.0                   pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.31.1               he774522_0
sqlitedict                1.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
swig                      3.0.12               h047fa9f_3    anaconda
typed-ast                 1.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
urllib3                   1.25.8                   pypi_0    pypi
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4
vs2015_runtime            14.16.27012          hf0eaf9b_1
wcwidth                   0.1.8                    pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.34.2                   py37_0
wincertstore              0.2                      py37_0
wrapt                     1.11.2                   pypi_0    pypi
zipp                      3.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
```

PyOptSparse "compatibility on Windows 64-bit has not been tested" [link](http://mdolab.engin.umich.edu/docs/packages/pyoptsparse/doc/install.html). I now believe this to be the issue.

**If anyone else has successfully installed PyOptSparse package on Windows (or any other operating system) please let me know.**

Comment: Are you installing it in the base environment?

Comment: @AMC sorry, yes I am.

Comment: You really shouldn't, I think you can find instructions online for resetting the base env. You can always reinstall Anaconda.

Comment: What's the issue with installing in the base environment?

Comment: You lose many of the benefits of using virtual environments, since you're mixing all your packages and installations.

Comment: Good point, I've just looked into it you're quite right. I am considering reinstalling Anaconda, do you know if there's any way to make sure I keep all the packages I was using?

Comment: _I am considering reinstalling Anaconda, do you know if there's any way to make sure I keep all the packages I was using?_ That depends on what you mean by _keep_. Were all your projects in the same environment?

Comment: By the look of things they would have all been in the base environment yes. Not to worry, I am starting again from scratch and doing it properly this time.

Comment: You can export the list of packages in the environment, and keep it as a reference just in case.

Comment: Ok, I have started again, installing Miniconda this time, setting up a virtual environment and reinstalling all the packages I had only to have the same error.

Comment: Only the relevant packages though, right?

Comment: Yep, only the relevant ones. I have hopefully learnt from last time.

Comment: Great! I will take another look at the issue you were having, but I don't know how much I will be able to do.